# How can I get the values of cartItem and make a n order?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, shopping-cart

How can I get the obj of the the cartItem and place an order?

here's how my **models.py** look like.

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

class CartItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    selected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

At frontend -

1. first get the list of Cart
2. Select a cart
3. Form an object with desired values.
4. Send this object to django.